# Given magnetic field, calculate electric field

Tags: electromagnetism

The B field depends on z and t so that
$B = j B_{0}cos(kz-\omega t)$ where k is the wavenumber, $\omega$ is angular frequency and $B_{0}$ is constant.
The electric field is $E = E_{x}i + E_{y}j +E_{z}k$. Given $E_{y}=E_{z}=0$, and $E_{x}=\frac{\omega B_{0}}{k}$ at $t=z=0$, determine an expression for $E_{x}$.

No idea where to even start! Kind of looks to me like there should be some integration involved, or differential equations, because I'd have some boundary conditions. Could I use Faraday's law of induction? Or Ampere's law? Confused!

Comment: If you apply Faraday's law you should end up having the electric field to be nothing but the magnetic field times the speed of light.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco Is that wrong then?

Comment: Take a surface and calculate the flux of the magnetic field through that surface. That must be equal to the electromotive force for the inductive electric field along the boundary of such surface. If you choose a circle in the $xy$ plan than the integrals should be easy to perform.